# How do I configure VS2012 test runner to pick up and run Gallio unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, gallio, test-runner

I've recently upgraded to VS2012 to iron out problems ahead of my team.  We use Gallio 3.3 as a unit tests framework and have numerous tests written which work in VS2010.  However, VS2012 does not appear to recognise them.

The VS2012 Test Explorer windows says "Build your solution to discover all available tests".  I have done several clean builds, and the system runs in VS2012, but no tests appear.

Is there any configuration I need to put in, or any way I can get these tests to run in VS2012?

Comment: I would be anxious to hear what the outcome is to your problem.  I am in the middle of evaluating mbUnit and ran into this same issue today.

Answer (score 1):

VS2012 UnitTestExplorer provides a platform to allow test frameworks to discover/execute tests. Currently, there're xUnit, nUnit, MSTest and a few other adapters available to work with VS2012.

For your Gallio tests to work with UnitTestExplorer, you will need a MBUnit adapter to discover/execute tests.

Currently, there's a MBUnitTest adapter which only works for VS2012 beta (come out around Feb this year). It comes with source code.  You can either

1. Download the code, make changes so it works with VS2012
2. File a request to the adapter writer and ask for making necessary changes.

Comment: Do you have a link on where to "download the code"?  I did a search for "mbunittest adapter" in both google, nuget, and VS's extensions and saw nothing.